# MySQLquery database against a string

Tags: mysql

I'm interested in searching for the database entries against a given string.

Something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE %table_column% LIKE %STRING%
```

is it possible to do this with MYSQL?

Thanks

Comment: DO you mean you want to search all columns for the same string?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't wildcard the column names. You can specify them like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE col1 LIKE %STRING%
or col2 LIKE %STRING%
or col3 LIKE %STRING%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic MySQL mostly inside stored procedure to accomplish this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
(
 arg_column_name VARCHAR(255)
,arg_filter VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

SET @query1 = CONCAT('
        SELECT  *
        FROM    table_name a
        WHERE   a.',arg_column_name,' LIKE "%',arg_filter,'%"'
        );
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;

CALL sp_test('column_name','filter_val');
```